# Conexão entre Active Directory e PHP, como fazer?

Tags: php, active-directory

Bom dia,
estou a fazer um trabalho para a escola e pediram me para fazer uma espécie de auto-preenchimento utilizando o AD (Active Directory), ou seja, através do ad poderia preencher o campo "Nome" e saber todas as permissões desse utilizador, mas não sei como fazê-lo.

A parte em que preciso de ajuda, é como é que faço a ligação entre o AD e o php, por exemplo no php tenho um campo "Nome do trabalhador" e como é que eu vou buscar o nome do trabalhador ao AD.

Answer (score 2):

O código abaixo não foi testado!

Para realizar essa tarefa, terá que observar os detalhes embutidos no processo

realizado pelo protocolo LDAP.

Habilite a extensão no arquivo php.ini

```
extension=php_ldap.dll
```

Descomente a linha acima.

```html
<?php

// sequência conecta, vincula , pesquisa ,trata a pesquisa , resultado e fecha conexão

// tipo mysql

echo "LDAP teste";

echo "Conectando ...";

$ds=ldap_connect("ldap.php.net"); // deve ser um servidor LDAP valido

echo "Resultado da conexão : " . $ds . "<br/>";

if ($ds) {

echo "Vinculando ...";

$r=ldap_bind($ds);

echo "Resultado: " . $r . "<br/>";

echo "Procurando por (campusid=000000137118)  ...";

$sr=ldap_search($ds, "ou=University of California Irvine,o=University of California, c=US", "campusid=000000137118");

echo "Resultado da pesquisa" . $sr . "<br/>";

echo "Número de entradas" . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br/>";

echo "Pega as entradas...<p>";

$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
   echo "Dados " . $info["count"] . "retornados:<p>";

for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
   echo "dn: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br/>";
   echo "Primeira cn: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br/>";
   echo "Primeiro tipo: " . $info[$i]["type"][0] . "<br/><hr/>";
   }

 echo "Fecha a conexão";
   ldap_close($ds);

} else {
   echo "Pi,pi, pi, piiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";
}
?>
```

Depois com os dados obtidos, monta uma função para que pegue os dados e exiba.

Qualquer dificuldade põe no comentário, pra gente ajustar.

### Recursos e referências:

[código acima](http://www.oit.uci.edu/idm/campusids/ldap-query-code-example-php/)  /
[Microsoft LDAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367033(v=vs.85).aspx)  /
[PHP LDAP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.ldap.php)